# Average of a continuous variable - double integral

Tags: calculus

The temperature of a particular point in the xy plane is given by $T(x, y)=x^2+y^2-xy^2$. Find average temperature of the square region bounded by $(x, y)=\{(0, 0), (10, 0), (0, 10), (10, 10)\}$.

Would this be the right place to take a double integral?
$$\int_{0}^{10}{\int_{0}^{10}{x^2+y^2-xy^2}}=\int_{0}^{10}{(x^3/3+xy^2-x^2y^2/2)\Big|_{0}^{10}}=\int_{0}^{10}{1000/3-40y^2}=(1000y/3-40y^3/3)\Big|_{0}^{10}=-10000$$ Then we divide by 10^2=100 since that is the sample space to get $-100$.

Is this right?

Comment: Exactly. In general, think of the average value theorem.

Comment: Thank you! But what if I wanted to integrate in the area bounded by $x^2+y^2 \le 1$ or some other curvy region?

Comment: You would do the same with the limits on the two integrals adjusted to account for the region, then divide by the area of the region.  For the unit circle you would integrate $y$ from $-1$ to $1$ and $x$ from $-\sqrt {1-y^2}$ to $+\sqrt {1-y^2}$ and divide by $\pi1^2$